# .NET Windows Form Application Fails Silently When Startup Object Is Sub Main And A Dependency Dll Is Not Present

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I noticed a different behavior between two .NET Windows Form Applications I am working on.

App A uses "Form1" for the Startup object. If a dependency dll is missing (e.g. I moved the dependency .dll to a "hidden" folder to purposely hide it) when I double-click AppA.exe the application complains loudly with the following exception which is what I would expect:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Library, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

However, App B uses "Sub Main" for its Startup object. If a dependency dll is missing (e.g. I moved the dependency .dll to a "hidden" folder to purposely hide it) when I double-click AppB.exe the application fails silently. Literally nothing happens when I double-click the .exe.

I'm thinking this is dangerous because failing silently is dangerous. Can someone help me understand why a Start object of "Form1" raises the missing dependency exception and a Startup object of "Sub Main" fails silently?

Ultimately I'd like to make it so my "Sub Main" app also throws the exception if a dependency is missing.

Here is the code for my Sub Main and AppDomain.UnhandledException event:

```
Public Sub Main()

  'Get the your application's application domain.
  Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain

  'Define a handler for unhandled exceptions.
  AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MYExHandler

  'Define a handler for unhandled exceptions for threads behind forms.
  AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf MYThreadHandler

  'Do some code here

End Sub

  Private Sub MYExHandler(ByVal sender As Object,
    ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    Dim EX As Exception
    EX = CType(e.ExceptionObject, Exception)
    MessageBox.Show(EX.StackTrace)
  End Sub

  Private Sub MYThreadHandler(ByVal sender As Object,
    ByVal e As Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.StackTrace)
  End Sub
```

Comment: Winforms applications also use the Main method. Check Program.cs. It seems likely you're just unable to see the output from your crashing console application because you're just double clicking it. I would expect to see the error in the console.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar note that it won't be Program.cs if it's `Sub Main` 

Comment: Post your Sub Main definition

Comment: *failing silently is dangerous* - maybe if it was silently deleting everything on the hard disk, but if it's just quitting I wouldn't call it dangerous.. inconvenient maybe. Why would dependencies be suddenly moved by the user anyway ?

Comment: Are both projects targeting the same framework? Is one .NET Framework and one .NET Core? Note that .NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core.

Comment: This is annoying Win10 behavior, find the crash notification back in the Application event log.  The Winforms plumbing uses the Application.ThreadException event to ensure that exceptions on the UI thread are easily visible.  Which isn't enough to ensure that *all* exceptions are visible.  So yes, you really do have to write an event handler for the AppDomain.UnhandledException event.

Comment: I'm using VB.net so it's Sub Main. Failing silently is dangerous in the sense that the user won't know what's going on and the error may not be reported. Yes, both projects are targeting the same .NET framework. I checked Event Viewer and see under Windows Log / Application the .NET Runtime error:

``The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at MyProgram.modLoader.Main()``

I do have full error handling in every method in my code. Can you provide sample code of an event handler for the AppDomain.UnhandledException event?

Comment: I found sample VB.net code for catching the AppDomain.UnhandledException event. I displayed a msgbox when such an event was caught. Sadly, my .exe still fails silently though the errors are showing up in Event Viewer. What else can I do?

Comment: @MatthewNYC you probably should start with posting the code for you Sub Main(), as requested by Caius Jard, and also posting your code for your UnhandledException event handler.

Comment: I added the code for my Sub Main and UnhandledException event handler to my original post. Please let me know if you see anything about that code that would fail to catch the error for a missing dependency.